# No puedo quitar segmentation fault de mi código

Tags: c, segfault

estoy teniendo problemas de segmentation fault con esta función y procedimiento. Pensé que podía ser porque me estaba yendo fuera de rango en el arreglo pero probe a mano los casos de prueba que me dieron y eso no sucede. Alguna idea?

```
struct _rep_cadena {
    TInfo cadena[L];
    nat cadena_tope;
};
TCadena insertarAlInicio(nat natural, double real, TCadena cad) {
    cad->cadena_tope = cad->cadena_tope + 1
    if (cantidadEnCadena(TCadena cad) == 0){
        cad->cadena_tope = cad->cadena_tope + 1;
        cad->cadena[0] = crearInfo(natural,real);
    }else{
        cad->cadena_tope = cad->cadena_tope + 1;
        for(int i = (cad->cadena_tope-1);i<0;i--){
            cad->cadena_tope[i+1] = copiaInfo(cad->cadena[i]);
            liberarInfo(cad->cadena[i]);
        }
        cad->cadena[0] = crearInfo(natural,real);
    }
    return cad;
void imprimirCadena(TCadena cad) {
    int m = (cantidadEnCadena(cad))
    if(m > 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
            imprimirInfo(cad->cadena[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }else{
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Comment: Probablemente estés escribiendo en una posición de memoria que no te pertenece.

Comment: Esta pregunta no hay por donde cogerla: la única estructura que indicas se llama `_rep_cadena` pero sin embargo usas el tipo `TCadena`. Hay funciones  como `cantidadEnCadena`, `imprimirInfo`, `copiaInfo` o `crearInfo`  que no aparecen en el código... y no olvidemos que al menos el resultado de la primera se usa en las funciones. He visto un error en el código, pero sin más información no veo conveniente dar ninguna respuesta

Comment: Trata de subir [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).