# Funcion en C++ siempre me da false

Tags: c++, funcion

tengo un problema con esta función, básicamente, se supone que funciona para decir si un numero natural(un int) se encuentra en una lista. Las listas están definidas como punteros(TCadena) a structs de este tipo:

```
struct _rep_cadena {
  TInfo info;
  TCadena next;
};
```

Donde TInfo son punteros a structs que dentro tienen un numero nat y un double.

```
    bool estaEnCadena(nat natural, TCadena cad) {
  bool esta = false;
  TCadena cadaux = cad;
  while((cadaux != NULL) && (esta = false)){
    if (natInfo(cadaux->info) != natural){
      cadaux = cadaux->next;
    }else{
      esta = true;
    }
  }
  return esta;
}
```

Básicamente, la funcion que uso ahí(natInfo()) es una funcion de la cual no se la implementacion que sé que me regresa el natural dentro de el Tinfo

Mi problema es que estaEnCadena siempre me da false, como si no entrara en el while, aunque esto ultimo no se si es cierto un 100% de las veces, la realidad es que no funciona como debería, ven algun error evidente que no esté viendo?

Comment: Tiene que ser `esta == false`, o mejor `!esta`. De la forma en la que lo haces, asignas `false` a `esta`, la expresion retorna `false`, terminando el `while`. El resultado de esto es que siempre retornaras false. Una pregunta, no seras compañero de clase o la segunda cuenta de @Ump? No puedo evitar notar las similitudes entre el código de tu pregunta [y el código en la suya](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/520876/no-puedo-quitar-segmentation-fault-de-mi-c%c3%b3digo).

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, ese era el problema!, estoy seguro de que debemos ser compañeros de clase, aunque somos demasiados en el grupo como para saber quien es, no tengo duda jaja

Answer (score 2):

en el while estas asignando `esta = false` en vez de comparamdo `esta == false`